How much does a ma'ah cost in £/$ in today's world?
To work out the exchange rate between the mishnayos/gemoroh money and nowadays to make the numbers more realistic.
EDIT 13.9.2024
to answer a few questions:
I meant in terms of purchasing power but i guess you could use silver value to get to there.

In terms of silver value, or purchasing power?

see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/135717/759 A sela is 24 maah

According to the table of coins in the "Practical Talmudic Dictionary" by R. Yitzchak Frank, מעה/Ma'ah is a silver coin weighing about 0.7 gram / 0.02251 oz (early opinion per Double AA), and more precisely 0.58 gram / 0.02046 oz (16 medium barley seeds). I will use the US dollar value of silver for comparison. Obviously market prices can vary from country to country.
Silver is a very soft metal. Due to high purity of the presently minted silver coins, they are sold in plastic casing for protection. Old silver coins were harder and obviously they did not have the same purity. The present cost of 0.999% pure silver bar is $31.31 USD per 1 oz. Therefore, the 0.90 pure silver should be about $28.75 USD per 1 oz (one needs to add the cost of additional weight) so that 1 ma'ah comes down to about $0.65 USD (old opinion) or $0.60 (more precisely).
As far as purchasing power, evidently, market prices changed all the time even in the times of Gemara. In masekhes Gittin 57a there is an example that 1 (silver) dinar could purchase 40 modios of grain, or 1 seah. The currently accepted volume of 1 seah is either 8.29 liter (R. Chaim Noeh) or 14.4 liter (Chazon Ish). It follows, that 1 ma'ah, which is 1/6 of a dinar, could be used to purchase 1.38 liter - 2.4 liter of wheat.
The comparison to current prices may not be meaningful because the agricultural commodities became cheaper due to advances in technology. The current price of wheat is about $6.1074 per bushel which is 36.368 liter or $0.167933 per 1 liter. Thus, we see that the wheat equivalent of 1 ma'ah would cost $0.23 - $0.403 today.
Production of silver also became much cheeper. R. Baruch Epstein in Torah Temimah (published in 1902) on Shemos 22:6 (comment עט) notes: that in his days the silver for two ma'ah was equivalent to 10 kopecks = 0.1 of the Russian Ruble. He says that in the time of gemara silver was much more expensive, and already in his time it was so cheap that one could not use it for oaths or marriage. Torah Temimah points to Tosafos in Menachos 107b, who notes this specific issue with the value of silver.
One can take over-all value of money from comparing minimal savings which prevented a person from getting gifts to the poor at the time of Mishna and now. Mishna Peah 8:8 states that a person in posession of 200 dinar cannot get gifts to poor. There does not seem to be a similar statistics on personal savings that prevent receiving government support. However, at present, to get by in most states to meet basic needs one needs between $30,000 and $45,000 annually depending on a state. Taking average of $37,000 as equivalent of 200 dinar, one gets about $31 per ma'ah. This value encapsulates all price reductions due to advances in technology.
There is another example in Mishna Hagiga 1:2 (suggested by ProfJames - thank you) which gives the minimal value of a lamb for the 'Olah (R'iyah) and Shlamim (Chagiga) offerings as 1 ma'ah or 2 ma'ah. The feeder lamb current prices (older than 9 days) are around $200-220 USD. In this case, advances in technology increased the value of domesticated animals by making them bigger. Based on the size of bones, as the video by Simcha Jacobovici attests, at the time of Mishna animals were smaller.
The market for old coins despite their lower silver purity is very different. Certainly, the antique value and the good condition of the rare coin could fetch a lot. Even not so antique, pre 1921 year 1oz Morgan silver dollar is sold for $49.95 USD compared to $28.20 value of its silver content.

+1 for the information.

Although in Ma'aser Sheni 2:8-9 and Bava Metzi'a 45a all the commentators say that מעה is a copper coin

@ba thank you. Possibly the commentators imply a different coin like a p'ruta (or issar according to Rosh)

0.58 grams is probably more historically accurate. 0.7 is aligned with some early opinions which don't match the historical numismatic record.

But in chagiga 2b Beis shammai and beis hillel argue about the cost of two different korbanos and they each say that the other type of korban costs 1 maah. So $0.60 seems like a very cheap price for an entire sheep, (that according to beis shammai had to be partly eaten by your entire family by the yom tov meal)?

@ProfJam the Mishna Chagiga 1:2 describes the minimal value of the offering suggested by the rabbis. Very likely, in a primarily animal herding society meat was cheaper than grain. Just to make a relative comparison, a new-born lamb, weight 7.7- 12 lbs with 40%-50% meat would yield 3.85 - 6 lbs of meat + skin, https://extension.sdstate.edu/lamb-birth-weights-relation-lamb-survivability. 1.38 liter/ma'ah of wheat would be grain weighting 2.28 lbs (density 60 lbs/bushel = 1.65 lbs/liter). Also there could be inflation after the destruction of the Temple.

@ProfJam animals were smaller compared to present, based on comparison of bones. I added a paragraph and reference about it.
